# Pandas object - save to .csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas object df and I would like to save that to .csv:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
```

Even if the data frame is displayed right in the terminal after printing, in the *.csv some lines are shifted several columns forward. I do not know how to demonstrate that in the minimal working code. I tried that with the one problematic column, but the result of one column was correct in the *.csv. What should I check, please? The whole column contains strings.

After advice:

```
selected['SpType'] = selected['SpType'].str.replace('\t', '')
```

I obtained an error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  selected['SpType'] = selected['SpType'].str.replace('\t', '')
```

Comment: Does it also occur if you use a different seperator then a comma?

Comment: Maybe you have tabulation instead of whitespace? Copy/Paste a such row in your question between backquotes.

Comment: I tried ; instead of , as a separator and the problem stayed.

Comment: Yes, there is a tab before items that are shifted. How to remove them? The data frame is a result of some filtering.

Comment: Are there strings that contain a comma themselves?

Comment: No, there are not commas in the strings. There are tabs before some items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tabs are the problem, you could just replace all tabs.

If the tabs occur in column `column_name` you could do something like:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace('\t', '')
```

If the problem is in several columns, you could loop over all columns. eg.:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('\t', '')

df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  selected['SpType'] = selected['SpType'].str.replace('\t', '')
What does it mean, please?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. You could change it to `df.loc[:, 'column_name'] = df.loc[:, 'column_name'].str.replace('\t', '')` if you want to get rid of the warning. Basically it means that you are making changes to a selection of the original dataframe and it is unsure if only the copy or also the original dataframe will be changed...